# Count Number of Events of SharePoint Calendar of Particular month and Year

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office-365-develop-tool, office-365-developer

I have task to count number of Events of Particular Month and Year from SharePoint Calendar. Can any one help me how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new view (standard view not calendar view) for the list and use filters to only show items between the appropriate dates, you can then use the "totals" section to count hoe many there are.

The whole solution can be found by using views.

Tal

Comment: Hi Through Event Recivers(Item Added) .When item or event is added I need to count the total  events of all the  particular month and year and show pop up info.And Below is the Query is not working.I created 2 columns in Calendar Month&Year to hold Name of Month and Year.Query not working

@"<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Year'/><Value Type='Calculated'>" + year + @"</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Month' /><Value Type='Calculated'>" + month + Value>
  </Eq></And> </Where>";

Comment: Hi samar. Pop up will not work in case of ItemAdded event receiver. Try to use ItemAdding instead of ItemAdded.

Comment: Also your query is not correct. What the formula in your calculated value?  and what is this ? - <Value Type='Calculated'>" + month + Value> - It is not correct. You should correct syntax of your query and change word 'Calculated' to something different. - https://sptalks.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/query-on-calculated-field-problem/